# KendoUI performance on huge (3000 items) json list

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

On Ionic Framework, there's a tool named "collection repeat". It ensures the good performance on huge lists like in `http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/mFygh`.

I tried to make the same idea on KendoUI, based on the `http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/databinding` example, but the performance is dead slow.

How can I improve the performance of KendoUI on this example?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you look at implementing paging (i.e. [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-listview/press-to-load-more) on the same page)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Brett, but indeed I tried. What worries me is that as the page is scrolled (pageSize + endlessScroll) all the items will be in memory. Ionic's listing keep only some items in display...